# UITableView gets muddled when using Ranorex Automation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ranorex

I am running automated tests on an IOS Application using Ranorex Studio.

The test loads a form, fills it out, and saves it.

I am getting varied results.

Field headings disappear as data is entered.

Data already entered disappears as more data is entered.

On date picker fields, the Done button sometimes disappears.

These problems only occur during automation, but Ranorex maintain that their automation does not change anything within the application.

There appears to be something completely random about what the UITableView decides to show.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Example: Section of log

[image: Section of log]

Screenshot before entering phone number

[image: Screenshot before entering phone number]

Screenshot after touching phone number field. Note: Field labels & required graphic (a red circle) are now missing.

[image: Screenshot after touching phone number field]

Snapshot before entering phone number

[image: Snapshot before entering phone number]

Snapshot after touching phone number

[image: Snapshot after touching phone number]

Comment: Are you building your UITableView programmatically or with Interface Builder?

Comment: It is all built in code.